# Is there a pandas method to do the opposite of "pandas.factorize" on dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any pandas method to unfactor a dataframe column? I could not find any in the documentation, but was expecting something similar to [unfactor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/varhandle/versions/2.0.5/topics/unfactor) in R language.

I managed to come up with the following  code, for reconstructing the column (assuming none of the column values are missing), by using the labels array values as indices of uniques.

```
orig_col = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']

labels, uniques = pd.factorize(orig_col)

recon_col = np.array([uniques[label] for label in labels]).tolist()

orig_col == recon_col
```

Answer (score 5):

```
orig_col = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b']
labels, uniques = pd.factorize(orig_col)

# To get original list back
uniques[labels]
# array(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it via `np.vectorize` and create the `dict`

```
np.vectorize(dict(zip(range(len(uniques)),uniques)).get)(labels)
array(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```